# Playing background YoutubeVideo in iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, youtube, avaudioplayer

I tryed to background play youtube video in iOS.

Back ground audio code.
`

```
- (BOOL) ensureAudio
{

// Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session (to get background sound)
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

// Set category
NSError *categoryError = nil;
if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&categoryError]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio session category could not be set");
    return NO;
}

// Activate session
NSError *activationError = nil;
if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio session could not be activated");
    return NO;
}

// Allow the audio to mix with other apps (necessary for background sound)
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    state = ENTER_BACKGROUND;
    // audio playing code
    [self checkPlay];
}
```

`

Youtube player api code

`function onPlayerStateChange(e){
        switch(e.data){
            case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                        play();
                window.location = "native://state_change";
        }
    }`

Success pattern is working onPlayerState.PAUSED.
Bad pattern is not working onPlayseState.PAUSED.

Comment: Does it works for you?